How to use the Lambert's W function on this exponential equation: $3-x^2=2^x$?
How to use the Lambert's W function on this exponential equation: $3-x^2=2^x$?
I am new to the Lambert's W function and there is barely anything I could find on Google.

What have you tried?

I have been trying for an hour I tired to split 3-x^2 as (√3-x)(√3+x) then I tried just raising (3-x^2)*2^-x=1 to the power of x but that did not work out. I am still in high school so I can't be sure if these approaches won't work but I am just confused at this point

Good job on noticing that $3-x^2=(\sqrt3-x)(\sqrt3+x)$, although you made a mistake raising it to the $x$th power. You should also multiply both sides by $2^{-x}$ to then get $(\sqrt3-x)(\sqrt3+x)2^{-x}=1$. Can you get it from there?

Oh thank you I will try it now

There was an answer but got deleted.

There is an answer that is wrong by answering a different question.

Fist show that there are precisely two real solutions. Notice that one of them is easy to find.

@Gary Haha, guess I did manage to miss $x=1$ as the only trivial sol. :)

Thank you I turned it into a quadratic and got -1.637 and +1 thanks for the help ig I gave up on (√3+x)(√3-x) too early

@Toshiv I think the reason it's giving you such a hard time is because not only is this non-algebraically solvable, we can't exactly rearrange anything due to the $x^2$ term. Newton's method would be a better choice for this type of problem

@Toshiv It is encouraged to share your solution by answering your own question.

There is an answer on the same kind of equation, but not with your $3$.

@CrSb0001 ok I will go learn it

@Gary I don't know how to type math on a computer

@peterwhy thanks for the link for the general solution

See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

This question could be given more details and work. However, there is this other series solution, and one with only a sum is possible too, after applying this theorem to $3-x=2^{-\sqrt x}$.

I give a method for real solutions.
$$3-x^2=2^x$$
$$3-x^2-2^x=0$$
We see, this equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x^2,2^x$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of elementary operations (means elementary functions) we can read from the equation.
But we can try to guess a solution. $x=1$ is one solution.
$$3-x^2=2^x$$
$$3-x^2=e^{\ln(2)x}$$
$$(-x^2+3)e^{-\ln(2)x}=1$$
Because $x$ in the factor and in the exponent of the exponential term are of different degree and the factor isn't only a power of $x$ at the same time, we cannot apply Lambert W here.
But the equation is in a form for applying Generalized Lambert W.
$x\to -\frac{t}{\ln(2)}$:
$$\left(-\frac{t^2}{\ln(2)^2}+3\right)e^t=1$$
$$\left(\frac{t^2}{\ln(2)^2}-3\right)e^t=-1$$
$$(t^2-3\ln(2)^2)e^t=-\ln(2)^2$$
$$(t-\sqrt{3}\ln(2))(t+\sqrt{3}\ln(2))e^t=-\ln(2)^2$$
$$(t-\sqrt{3}\ln(2))(t-(-\sqrt{3}\ln(2)))e^t=-\ln(2)^2$$
$$t=W\left(^{\sqrt{3}\ln(2),-\sqrt{3}\ln(2)}_{};-\ln(2)^2\right)$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}W\left(^{\sqrt{3}\ln(2),-\sqrt{3}\ln(2)}_{};-\ln(2)^2\right)$$
So we have a closed form for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

With Bessel polynomials
$$y_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} e^{\frac{1}{x}} K_{-n-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
The generalized LambertW function is
$$W(t_1,t_2;a)=t_1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n n!} \left(\frac{a n e^{-t_1}}{t_2-t_1}\right)^n\cdot y_{n-1}\left(-\frac{2}{n(t_2-t_1)}\right) $$
